# Alternative to pytest namespace after upgrade to 3.7.4 - Error: unknown hook 'pytest_namespace'

Tags: python

I did an upgrade to the latest 3.7.4 and I have seen that pytest namespaces are deprecated https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#pytest-namespace

I geet an error when I run pytest against a module:

```
pluggy.manager.PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_namespace' in plugin <module
```

I have a small conftest.py file where I parse out some variables from database locations and similar. An then I use those variables (from def pytest_namespace() function) inside the pytest module file.
But then I get the hook error test.

Is there some alternative to use, so that I do not have to rebuild a lot of code?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: same here , u got anything  ??

Answer (score 15):

The clue is to change the way of thinking in the latest pytest version. `pytest_namespace` according to the [changelog](https://docs.pytest.org/en/latest/deprecations.html#pytest-namespace) is depreciated. So now you have to instead of:

```
# conftest.py
def pytest_namespace():
    return dict(something_func: your_function, something_class: your_class)
```

use:

```
# conftest.py
def your_function():
    ...

class your_class:
    ...

def pytest_configure():
    pytest.something_func   = your_function
    pytest.something_class  = your_class()
```

Comment: This should be accepted except I found the use of a function that returns a string 'nothing' to be rather confusing. In the end the edits to your answer are significant so feel free to reject and I will create a separate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Got the same kind of issue related to pytest_namespace.

1. Ran test-suite from the parent directory of testing source code (issue present)
2. Then traversed to each subdirectory and ran the test-suite (issue still persists)

Then I decided to install any external plugins which might have the default pytest_namespace defined.

Don't know whether this is an actual answer or not. But I found that installing external plugins related to the pytest plugins resolved my issue.

This could be a dumb approach

**Steps followed:**

1. Clear old residual files related to pytest in your source code directory
    `rm -rf .pytest_cache __pycache__`
2. Installed following pytest packages.

```html
pip install pytest-assume==1.2
pip install pytest-cagoule==0.3.0
pip install pytest-cov==2.6.0
pip install pytest-csv==1.1.2
pip install pytest-expect==1.1.0
pip install pytest-html==1.19.0
pip install pytest-json==0.4.0
pip install pytest-metadata==1.7.0
pip install pytest-pdb==0.3.1
pip install pytest-pylint==0.14.0
pip install pytest-raises==0.9
pip install pytest-rerunfailures==6.0
pip install pytest-timeout==1.3.2
pip install pytest-xdist==1.8
pip install python-dateutil==2.7.3
```

After the successful installation of the above plugins, Somehow the `PluginValidationError: unknown hook 'pytest_namespace' in plugin` error did not come later on.

Currently working on it to find the actual reason.